# remote NFS config via script results

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh

I am really new to this - and I am mostly doing this for practice. I am trying to create a script that will allow the deployment of LEMP across multiple servers and allow "NFS" configuration depending on the server IP, etc. Basically, just a script that allows upward scalability with as much automation as possible. Sorry if I sound ignorant - I am pretty new!

So far, I the installation of LEMP automatically was simple and easy for me to put together. It's definitely a bit messy with the SSHkeys. I'll clean it up as much as I can as soon as I can figure out what I am doing wrong with the variable section. Essentially, everything is being added to /etc/exports on a new line EXCEPT for the IP variable. I believe it's because it's a local variable and I am doing it remotely? Thanks!

Here is the part I am having trouble with:

```
for NFS in $(cat nfs.txt)
do
        for hostname in $(cat hostname.txt)
        do
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh root@$NFS mkdir -p .ssh
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@$NFS 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
ssh root@$hostname mkdir -p .ssh
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@$hostname 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
ssh root@$hostname "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
ssh root@$NFS "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
IP=`ssh root@$hostname  ifconfig | grep Bcast | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d" " -f1`
echo $IP > ip.txt
scp ip.txt root@$hostname:ip.txt
IPLOCAL=`cat ip.txt`
ssh root@$NFS 'echo -e "/var/www/html        $IPLOCAL(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)" >> /etc/exports'
done
done
```

This is what I originally had

```
for NFS in $(cat nfs.txt)
do
for hostname in $(cat hostname.txt)
do
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh root@$NFS mkdir -p .ssh
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@$NFS 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
ssh root@$hostname mkdir -p .ssh
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@$hostname 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
ssh root@$hostname "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
ssh root@$NFS "chmod 700 .ssh; chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys"
IP=`ssh root@$hostname ifconfig | grep Bcast | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d" " -f1`
ssh root@$NFS 'echo -e "/var/www/html $IP(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)" >> /etc/exports'
done
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set value of remote variable as local, you have to use syntax like this.

```
localValue='local'
ssh user@remote 'remoteValue='"$localValue;"'echo remoteValue'
```

So if I understand your purpose correctly, you should write code like this:

```
...
IP=`ssh root@$hostname ifconfig | grep Bcast | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d" " -f1`
for i in $IP
do
ssh root@$NFS 'echo -e /var/www/html '"$i"'(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check) >> /etc/exports'
done
...
```

Comment: Try not to use -c to run you script.

Comment: It worked, I just had to add a " before and after the ( ) so that it looks like

ssh root@$NFS 'echo -e /var/www/html "'$IPREMOTE'(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)" >> /etc/exports'

Comment: Someone upvote the gentleman - I am new and don't have 15 rep yet:(